Predicting electrical mean free path in nanostructures?
How does one roughly predict the
mean free path for
electrical conduction
in a nanostructure at different temperatures and under different electrical conditions such as different voltages and amperages based on the composition and dimensions of the structure?
For instance in
carbon single and multilayer nanotubes vs graphene ribbons vs silicon nanowires, and all of different sizes.
In other words how do I predict the average range of electrical ballistic conduction in a described structure under different power and temperature conditions?
